# How do I reorder my data to be in clusters in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to visualize my data into clusters. Here is my attempt so far. I would like to somehow reorder the genes such that the color groups in each organ are roughly grouped together into blocks. Obviously that's impossible for all the colors to be in blocks barring a statistical miracle, but if possible to have at least the top frequency color block in each organ at least be blocked, instead of the random assortment of colors it is in now. I hope I'm being somewhat clear.

So in summary, ref needs to be in one solid block of blue and then one solid block of red. Then the next color with the highest frequency is orange in organ1, so I'd like that to be a block or at least two blocks. That's probably the best I can hope for but if I can procedural-ly put the rest of the colors into the best blocks that can be arranged that'd be great. Also, no idea why ref has red and blue mixed up.

Or uh if anyone knows of an visual implementation of this that's already out there I'd appreciate it if someone can point me in that direction.

```
library(ggplot2)
test <- data.frame(genes = paste0("gene", 1:100), ref = c(rep("blue", 50), rep("red", 50)), organ1 = colors()[sample(c(1:3, NA), size = 100, replace = T)], organ2 = colors()[sample(c(4:6, NA), size = 100, replace = T)], 
                   organ3 = colors()[sample(c(7:9, NA), size = 100, replace = T)])
test[is.na(test)] <- "grey"

ggplot(melt(test, id.vars = "genes"), aes(x = genes, y = variable, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + coord_fixed(ratio = 10) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image: heatmap]

Comment: Is it important to keep observations together for each variable? or do you simply just want each row of the plot to have all the colors blocked together?

Comment: Yes, the observations need to be together, which is why I doubt that I can arrange anything more than one or two of the colors into blocks of some form

Comment: right. so your best bet would then be `arrange()` within the `dplyr` package. I would check out some examples to help figure out how you can use it to acquire your desired results. it will allow you to arrange on multiple variables as well. so if you did `arrange(test, ref, organ1)`, it will first put all the colors together for ref, then within each color of ref, group the colors of organ1 together. and you can do this for all four variables. I believe that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment made it seem perhaps a bit easier than I led on. There's some nuances with `ggplot2`, namely that it will automatically factor character strings in a plot call, and change the ordering we obtained with arrange. To avoid this, we just have to do the factoring ourselves, with the levels in the order of the genes we get after arranging them. I copied your code and added to it. Also, on my end, there was issues with setting NA's to grey, and I solved this by making the character strings in your data set not automatically be factors.

```
library(ggplot2)
test <- data.frame(genes = paste0("gene", 1:100), ref = c(rep("blue", 50),rep("red", 50)), organ1 = colors()[sample(c(1:3, NA), size = 100, replace = T)], organ2 = colors()[sample(c(4:6, NA), size = 100, replace = T)], 
               organ3 = colors()[sample(c(7:9, NA), size = 100, replace = T)], stringsAsFactors = F)
test[is.na(test)] <- "grey"
test1 <- test %>%
  arrange(ref, organ1, organ2, organ3)
test1$genes <- factor(test1$genes, levels = test1$genes)
test2 <- test1  %>%
  gather(key = "variable", "value", -genes)
ggplot(test2, aes(x = genes, y = variable, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + coord_fixed(ratio = 10) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]